# MATE Desktop "WindowList"-applet has two rows - how can I change back to single?

Tags: desktop, mate-desktop, panel

A few days ago, my children played with my linux pc (MATE Desktop 1.18.0), and they pressed some keys or key-combinations.

After this, the "WindowList" applet in the gnome panel is displaying the opened windows in two rows, and the icons and window titles are very small.
I've still searched for an option to set the number of rows or something, but didn't found anything.

I found answers, that said that I just have to change the panel size/height, but the panel size is the same size as before. And when I change the panel height to a lower one (36px->24px), it **doesn't** change the number of rows in the WindowList applet. :-(

How can I set it back to a single row?